# Crash after implementing Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have implemented a `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter that adds a my own custom objects made from the my class `Item`. Now I am trying to add a Spinner that will have a list of `Strings` where when you click on an object in the `Spinner` drop down menu, it will change the content of the `RecyclerView`. Basically where each choice in the `Spinner` will have its own list for the `RecyclerView`. But when I try to add content to the `Spinner`, the app crashes when I try to start it. This is the code I added to `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` that made the app crashed:

```
  ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
  lists.add("firstList");
  lists.add("secondList");
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lists);
  dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I thought it might be crashing because the ArrayAdpater somehow conflicts with my custom `ItemAdapter`, but I am not sure because I am new to using adapters. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

If it will help I have my custom adapter here:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Item> mItemList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private int selectedPosition=-1;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;

        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
        mItemList = itemList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, viewGroup, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder exampleViewHolder, final int position) {
        Item currentItem = mItemList.get(position);

        exampleViewHolder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        exampleViewHolder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());

        if(selectedPosition==position)
            exampleViewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
            exampleViewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        exampleViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.positionOfChosenItem = position;
                selectedPosition = position;
                MainActivity.btnChange.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.changeAmountField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemList.size();
    }
```

EDIT: I have made sure that the variables are set to the right value like setting `dropdown` to the `Spinner` in the layout.
         `dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner);`
And have set contentView to the layout, that the `Spinner` lies in. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

EDIT: Here is the error as well:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.barxqrscanner2, PID: 20357
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.barxqrscanner2/com.example.barxqrscanner2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.barxqrscanner2.MainActivity.buildDropDown(MainActivity.java:123)
            at com.example.barxqrscanner2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Please post stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: use setOnItemClicklistener method for spinner item clickand then write a recyclerview adapter there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error (NullPointerException) is due to this line:

```
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Your object `dropdown` seems to be `null`.

I think you forgot to instantiate this object, or you are calling `setAdapter()` before instantiating `dropdown`. But without the rest of the code, it is difficult to tell more precisely what's the real problem.

Best

Comment: Yes! it was precisely like you said. Thank you for the assist!

Comment: Happy to help :)